# Записать из базы данных значение в переменную Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

```
public function index(){
     $user=auth()->user();
             return view('admin.articles.index',[
              'articles' => Article::with(['user' => function ($query) {  $query->where('role_id','=', 1)->where('role_id','=', 3);}])- 
             >orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10, ['*'], 'main_user_table'),

         'articles_suggest' => Article::with(['user' => function ($query) {  $query->where('role_id', 2) ;}])- 
              >orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10, ['*'], 'suggestion_user_table'),
        ]);
}
```

Я  хочу вывести данные статей, у которых автор будет через таблицу пользователей role_id = 1 и 3 , но почему то в переменную записывается прям всё ,все статьи , а когда я пытаюсь через IF проверить , то всегда вторая страница пустая, у первой 2 записи , все остальные на третий странице.  Мне просто нужно , чтобы в переменную articles записалось только, только , только записи у который автор по роли 1 или 3 . Я не понимаю что не так...

```
 @forelse ($articles as $article)
      @if (isset($article->user->role_id))
         @if (($article->user->role_id!=2))
            <tr>
              <td>{{$article->title}}</td>
             <td>{{$article->published}}</td>
            </tr>
        @endif
    @endif
  @empty
```

Article model

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'author_id');
  }
```

User model

```
public function articles(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Article');
    }
```

index.php

```
   public function index(){
     $user=auth()->user();
      return view('admin.articles.index',[
         'articles' => Article::with('user')->whereHas('user', function ($query) { $query->whereIn('role_id', [1,2]); } )->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10, ['*'], 'main_user_table'),

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. В этом фрагменте кода запрашиваются все записи `Article`. Указанный внутри запрос применяется только при загрузке отношения `user`.

```
Article::with(['user' => function ($query) {  $query->where('role_id','=', 1)->where('role_id','=', 3);}])
```

2. В этом фрагменте кода у вас будет сгенерирован sql вида `where role_id = 1 and role_id = 3`, я бы предложил вам `where role_id in (1, 3)`.

```
$query->where('role_id','=', 1)->where('role_id','=', 3);
```

3. Для решения вашей задачи можно воспользоваться методом `whereHas`, с которым можно подробнее ознакомиться в [документации Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence). В вашем случае достаточно будет заменить код, который я указал в пункте 1 на этот.

```
Article::with('user')->whereHas('user', function ($query) {
    $query->whereIn('role_id', [1, 3]);
});
```

Comment: Да всёравно он почему то все берёт , а не те, которые мне нужны....

Comment: а если делаю проверку через IF то непонятно что происходит... на певрой странице  две записи , на второй не одной , на третий четыре записи.... они все должны идти одна за другой.. ай не понимаю

Comment: там ещё , если через var_dump смотреть , то записи повторяються в самом object. каждая запись дублируется два раза

Comment: Предложенный вариант решения не изменил ничего вообще? Если есть возможность, то покажите получившийся код в `public function index()`. Также интересует, как описано отношение `user` в модели `Article`.

Comment: Добавил в вопрос, посмотрите , пожалуйста

Comment: Ещё есть предположение, что не для каждой из статей существуют пользователь в таблице. Если в шаблоне убрать проверку `@if (isset($article->user->role_id))`, то ничего не поменяется? Конечно, в идеале нужно самостоятельно проверить это в базе данных.

Comment: Также в вашем примере сейчас делается `$query->whereIn('role_id', [1,2]);`, а на выводе в шаблоне есть проверка `@if (($article->user->role_id!=2))`, которая не даст вывести пользователей с `role_id = 2`. Если вы, конечно, не вносили соответствующие изменения в шаблон.

Comment: да я убрал все проверки IF и тд . всеравно не работает